# Associate Survey to a Case

Tags: case, survey

I have created a survey using survey builder, whose link will be sent to a related contact of case when case is closed. Surveys are being captured into Survey Analyze tab, i want that survey response to get attached to related case. so that Case owner or any one can see response of contact.

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the blogs to achieve your requirement to release the survey to the relevant case. (this is possible with the help of process builder and flow
https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/send-salesforce-survey-without-writing-code/

Thanks & Regards,
​​​​​​​Sakthivel Madesh

Comment: Is this still the recommended way of associating responses to a record?